# How to display .doc/pdf files from phpMyAdmin on web page using php?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

We are using this code to retrieve the data from database its showing the whole data but i want to retrieve the .doc attachment too but its not showing that..

```
<?php

 $con = mysql_connect("your.hostname.com","abc","abc");



mysql_select_db("car1319108511185",$con);
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `wp_rsjp_submissions` LIMIT 0 , 30";
$comments = mysql_query($query);
echo "<h1> Applications </h1>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($comments, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $name = $row['fname'];
    $lname = $row['lname'];
    $address1 = $row['address'];
    $address2 = $row['address2'];
    $city = $row['city'];
    $state = $row['state'];
    echo '<iframe src='$row['attachment']'/>';




    echo "<div style='margin:30px 0px;'>
        First Name: $name<br/>
        Last Name : $lname<br/>
        Address : $address1<br/> $address2<br/>
        City : $city <br/>
        State : $state <br/>

         <br/>
        </div>";

        }


        mysql_close($con);

        ?>
```

It showing me error on line 20 that is:

```
  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/content/48/11655748/html/display_comments.php on line 20
```

Please help me guys how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Fix your quotes:

```
echo '<iframe src="' . $row['attachment'] . '"/>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply it showing me a frame but its doesn't showing me my doc file or pdf file how to show that files from phpadmin..

Comment: Set the doctype in the HTML.